# How can this RF amplifier increase the voltage above power supply level?

Tags: voltage, amplifier, rf

It must be something simple I am not getting in electronics, but this UHF RF amplifier (of which China has helpfully erased the part number on what I take is the transistor) produces 13 watts of output power while only takes 12-15 volts of supply power. Now 13 watts at 50 ohms corresponds to 25.5 Vrms or 72.1 V peak-to-peak. All this is apparently possible **without an inductor**, at least I don't see one. How can this be done?

[image]

Comment: *this UHF RF amplifier [...] produces 13 watts of output power* It may well do that, but unless you've measured this yourself, I wouldn't jump to conclusions. It is **marketed** as producing 13W of output power. That's all we know at this point. It may well work as advertised, but neither you nor us know it yet.

Comment: Yes I measured it.

Comment: Need a schematic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are basically an RF amplifier, often multistage, with the input and output impedance matched, often to 50\$\Omega\$ but 75\$\Omega\$ is also common. They’re typically on a ceramic substrate and use stripline as well as conventional solenoid inductors. I’ve seen them without the cover on them, they definitely have inductors.

Answer (score 2):

Your so-called transistor has four pins.  A transistor would have only three pins.  It is quite likely (almost certainly) an amplifier module that contains the required inductor as well as the power transistor.

---

As an example, [here's an RF power amplifier module from Philips. 29 watts of output power into a 50 ohm antenna from 12.5VDC.](https://www.rf-microwave.com/en/philips/bgy145a/vhf-power-amplifier-module/bgy145a/)

Comment: Do you, or does anyone know a part number of such a component? Is it really called 'amplifier module'? I cannot find something that looks like it.

But all in all, you are pretty sure there is an inductor in there? Without it it cannot be done, right?

Comment: It is probably as something like [this amplifier module.](https://www.rf-microwave.com/en/philips/bgy145a/vhf-power-amplifier-module/bgy145a/) 29 watts from 12.5V into a 50 ohm antenna.

Comment: they don't show any inductors inside in the datasheet, only 2 opamps in series... is it safe to assume this is just simplification? Because they actually suggest to use 2 small inductors.

Comment: The internal circuit diagram is very much simplified in the datasheet.

Answer (score 1):

As you mention using an inductor it is possible to swing above the supply voltage.

Another thing properly relevant in this case, is matching circuitry which transforms the load usually 50 ohm to a lower impedance at the transistor. This is properly embedded in this module.

If you look into resonant circuit the same applies where it is possible to have higher voltage or current than the supply.

Comment: Yeah I know it can be done with an inductor, but on this one I don't see one... That's my problem.